# How to pass array values to function onChange from input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tableau-api, daterangepicker

I am calling a function named "VizDateRange" which receives two parameters when dates are selected and these selected values should pass as two values but the selected dates are in a weird format which comes out as 02/01/2017-06/19/2017 as one value. So,in order to pass it as two values, how should I proceed?

//HTML

```
<div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" name="" title="Select date range">
            <input type="text" id="daterange" class="form-control" onChange=VizFilter(this.val().split(" - "))>  //this is not working obviously. 
        </div>
```

//calling daterangepicker which is bootstrap's date range plugin

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
            var dp = $('#daterange').daterangepicker({

                "startDate": "02/06/2017", setting the limit for min
                "endDate": "06/19/2017"setting the limit for max
            }


            )

        });
```

//the output is

02/01/2017-06/19/2017

// but what I need is "02/01/2017","06/19/2017" in order to pass it to VizDateRange function.

//so I can use split (" - ") to turn it to array but how to pass this onChange or onClick from input field?

//the function should get called onChange or onCLick and it asks for two values, it receives two parameters

```
 function vizDateRange(minDate,maxDate)

            {
                sheet = viz0.getWorkbook().getActiveSheet();
                worksheetsArray = sheet.getWorksheets();
                for (var i = 0; i < worksheetsArray.length; i++) {
                    worksheetsArray[i].applyRangeFilterAsync("WEEK(DCM Date)", {
                        min: new Date(minDate),
                        max: new Date(maxDate)

                    });
                }
};
```

//here is jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/u4t1rebs/

Comment: what specific library are you using for daterangepicker? I bet it has a built in on change function you could use

Comment: it is pretty much asking how to get the values from daterangepicker and edit it before I pass it to another function? and it has to occur everytime new daterange is selected.

Comment: @DelightedD0D it is www.daterangepicker.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [library's examples](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#examples) the first argument is an options object, but as a second optional argument you can pass a callback function. Here's how I would use that callback to solve this issue:

```js
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var dp = $('#daterange').daterangepicker({
                    "startDate": "02/06/2017",
                    "endDate": "06/19/2017"
                },
                function(start, end, label) {
                 start = moment(start).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
                    end = moment(end).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
                    vizDateRange(start, end)
                }
            )
        });


        function vizDateRange(minDate, maxDate) {
            // do stuff here 
            console.log(minDate, maxDate);
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include Required Prerequisites -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- Include Date Range Picker -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />


<div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" name="" title="Select date range">
  <input type="text" id="daterange" class="form-control" > //this is not working obviously.
</div>
```

Comment: wow. it is working!!! thank you! I will read the library examples more in order not to repeat this type of mistakes again. Thank you!